# create Pod with bridging header

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, newrelic

I'm trying to create a pod `APod` which has a 'AAnalytics' as a subspace. ''AAnalytics' has multiple dependencies such as `Firebase` and `NewRelic`. Here's how the `podspec` looks like:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'APod'
  s.version          = '0.3.5'
  s.summary          = 'summary'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.tvos.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.watchos.deployment_target = '2.0'
  s.static_framework = true
  s.source_files = 'APod/Classes/*'

  #### Subspec ####
  s.subspec 'AAnalytics' do |ss|
    ss.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'Yes' }
    ss.source_files = 'Classes/AAnalytics/*'
    ss.dependency 'NewRelicAgent', '~> 5.15.0'
    ss.dependency 'Analytics', '~> 3.6.0'
    ss.dependency 'Segment-Adjust', '~> 1.1.3'
    ss.dependency 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.27.1'
    ss.dependency 'Firebase/Core', '~> 4.4.0'
  end
end
```

In `AAnalytics`, it has only one class `AAnalytics.swift` which has a wrapper methods of dependency pods. Everything works fine except `NewRelicAgent`. I can't import and use `NewRelicAgent` in `Analytics.swift`. However I could use `NewRelicAgent` in main project with bridging header.

After I searched for a while, I found that Xcode doesn't create module.modulemap file for `NewRelicAgent` (or it should be included in `NewRelicAgent` pod).

[image]

As you see above, `FirebaseAnalytics` has `Modules/module.modulemap'.

[image]

However `NewRelicAgent` doesn't have the path and file.

I have read this [article](http://nsomar.com/modular-framework-creating-and-using-them/) and it seems Xcode create `module.modulemap` file if `DEFINES_MODULE = Yes` and there is a umbrella header which has same name with framework.

What am I missing and What should I do to use `NewRelicAgent` from `AAnalytics.swift`? I'm using `cocoapods 1.4.1 beta 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode doesn't generates `module.modulemap` files for binary frameworks. `NewRelicAgent` is a [vendored_framework binary CocoaPod](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/1/a/2/NewRelicAgent/5.15.0/NewRelicAgent.podspec.json#L20) that doesn't include a module map. Other CocoaPod's include a `module.modulemap` within their framework.

If you do `find . | grep module.modulemap`, you'll see that the other binary CocoaPods with public APIs in your project include a `Modules/module.modulemap` file.

Comment: So there is no way to use in this way?

Comment: After `pod install`, you could add a Pods/NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent/NewRelicAgent.framework/Modules/module.modulemap with the right contents